# MongoDB - Conditionally match two arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

There is the following array of objects:

```
let externalArray = 
[
 { name: "xxx",
   max: 100,
   unit: "myUnit"
 },
 { name: "yyy",
   max: 90,
   unit: "myUnit"
 }
]
```

And the following mongodb structure:

```
[
    {
        "myList": [
            {
                "name": "xxx",
                "amount": 66.3,
                "unit": "myUnit"
            },
            {
                "name": "yyy",
                "amount": 11.6,
                "unit": "myUnit"
            },
            {
                "name": "zzz",
                "amount": 6.9,
                "unit": "myUnit"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I use the $match query inside an aggregation to only output the objects for which myList.amount <= externalArray.max and myList.unit equals externalArray.unit for the same name? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately no... as I am trying to dynamically use values from an external array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're comparing against input array to an array in documents you need to do few more things along with `$filter` :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** Unwind (Split array into objects :: total docs = each doc * no.of objects in array of respective doc) */
    {
      $unwind: "$myList"
    },
    /** Iterate on input `externalArray` & check for all conditions. Creates an array field `matches` */
    {
      $addFields: {
        matches: {
          $filter: {
            input: externalArray,
            cond: {
              $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.name", "$myList.name" ] },
                { $eq: [ "$$this.unit", "$myList.unit" ] },
                { $lte: [ "$myList.amount", "$$this.max" ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    /** In filter step if it matches with any condition then `matches` will have 1 or more objects from `externalArray` 
     * Excluding all docs where there is no match */
    {
      $match: { matches: { $ne: [] } }
    },
    /** Remove unnecessary field */
    {
      $project: { matches: 0 }
    },
    /** Since we unwind the array - group back all docs based on `_id` */
    {
      $group: { _id: "$_id", myList: { $push: "$myList" } }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6NgcJ7c0Rsw)

**Note :**

In the response :

1. `myList` array will contain only matched objects from `externalArray`.
2. You don't see documents where `myList` is not present or if no matching object exists between `myList` & `externalArray` (So there should be at-least one matching object between two arrays in order to get the document out).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you so much! It definitely solves my initial question and I am going to mark your answer as correct, but I've just realised I have two other lists like "myList" in my db structure. Shall I unwind all of them and go through the same steps? But how am I going to group everything at the end? Just with _id: "$_id" it seems not to work.

Comment: @andfrst : Oh ok, Often arrays & nested arrays will always be an issue not just in MongoDB but in programming languages as well :-) Even this query is a bit complex if used on huge datasets(try to filter docs in initial stages) !
Unless we see the data we can't say anything.. Maybe you can raise a new question with sample data(entire doc) & required o/p - someone can help you with a query..

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your external array before passing it to aggregation pipeline to be the following structures and use as conditions.

We can use this in a `$match` expression to match the documents that has at least one match.

```
[{
  "name": "xxx",
  "amount": {
    "$lte": 100
  },
  "unit": "myUnit"
},
{
  "name": "yyy",
  "amount": {
    "$lte": 90
  },
  "unit": "myUnit"
}]
```

```js
/* example js implementation */
const matchConditions = externalArray.map(({ name, max, unit })=> ({
  name,
  amount: { $lte: max },
  unit
}))
```

And we can use the following in the `$filter` condition

```
[{
  "$and": [
    { "$eq": ["name", "xxx"] },
    { "$lte"  ["amount", 100 },
    { "$eq": ["unit", "myUnit"] }
  ]
},
{
  "$and": [
    { "$eq": ["$$this.name", "yyy"] },
    { "$lte":  ["$$this.amount", 90 },
    { "$eq": ["$$this.unit", "myUnit"] }
  ]
}]
```

```
/* example js implementation */
const filterConditions = externalArray.map(({ name, max, unit }) => ({
  $and: [
    { $eq: ['$$this.name', name] },
    { $lte:  ['$$this.amount', max },
    { $eq: ['$$this.unit', unit] }
  ]
}))
```

Then finally we can use the following aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      myList: {
        $elemMatch: {
          $or: matchConditions
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      myList: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$myList',
          cond: {
            $or: filterConditions
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, thank you.